# Использование вложенных объектов в json на Java?

Tags: java, json, vkontakte-api

```
{
"response": {
    "count": 98,
    "items": [
        {
            "id": 4112,
            "from_id": 14678,
            "owner_id": 14678,
            "date": 1432924043,
            "post_type": "post",
            "text": "Динь-дон",
            "comments": {
                "count": 0
            },
            "likes": {
                "count": 561
            },
            "reposts": {
                "count": 27
            }
        }
    ]
}
}
```

Как добраться, скажем до значения `ownerd_id`? Чтобы возвращало значение 14678?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 3):

Пример реализации с помощью Jackson:

```
public class Response {
    public int count;
    public List<Item> items;

    class Item {
        public int id;
        public int from_id;
        public int owner_id;
        public Date date;
        public String post_type;
        public String text;
        public Comment comments;
        public Like likes;
        public Repost reposts;
    }

    class Comment {
        public int count;
    }

    class Like {
        public int count;
    }

    class Repost {
        public int count;
    }
}
```

В нужном месте вызвать так:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
Response response = mapper.readValue(json, Response.class);
System.out.println(response.items[0].owner_id); //выведет первый
```

Comment: А без класса-сущности возможно?

Comment: @arg считывайте не в объект отдельной сущности, а в HashMap, кто же мешает

Answer (score 0):

Достаточно парсить json, подключив библиотеки `JSONObject`, `JSONArray`, `JSONException`. 
Например, так. Писал на память, не факт, что корректно сработает, но суть уловить можно.

```
try {
    JSONArray items = (JSONArray) ((JSONObject) ((JSONObject) response.json).get("response")).getJSONArray("items");
    JSONObject item = (JSONObject) items.get(0);
    String owner_id = item.getString("owner_id");
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

В интернете есть подробные описания процесса парсинга json

Comment: А что, стандартные пакеты Явы содержат эти классы? указывайте библиотеку

Comment: ознакомьтесь http://www.json.org/java/index.html

Comment: пожалуй останусь я на джексоне. А этот шлак я буду чтоли с гит репозитория клонировать?

Comment: @arg не волнуйтесь вы так http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.json%7Corg.json%7Cchargebee-1.0%7Cjar

Comment: @Etki спасибо !